# Remove the backslash "\" present only at the end of each columns in a Spark dataframe?

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe. I need to remove the backslash "\" only at the end of each column from the dataframe.

I have tried the following code but it replaces all the "\" from the dataframe.

```
val df2 = df.columns.foldLeft(df)((df, c) => df.withColumn(c, regexp_replace(col(c), "\\\\", "")))
```

**But I need to remove backslash which is present at the end of each column.**

**sample input row:**

349272|SET\CURVE\|SHE\HE|MBHG\

**Expected output row:**

349272|SET\CURVE|SHE\HE|MBHG

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, given what you tried, what was the outcome ? Different from the expected ?

Comment: In regexp_replace(col(c), "\\|", "|")  the escape pattern "\\|" is not recognized as \| so it doesn't get replaced by |. The input and the output is same in this case.

Comment: If you have a true quoted string, to delete these separate literal characters \ and | requires that each be escaped since they are both regex metachars. So, use `"\\\\\\|"` Where \ => `"\\\\"` and | => `"\\|"` The regex engine should then see \\\|

Comment: Let me know if this works

Comment: `But I need to only replace backslash which is present before pipe delimter.` In this case, you could use the replace like you originally did, except with the regex mentioned. `"\\\\\\|","|"` or you could do it like this  `"\\\\(?=\\|)",""`

Comment: What's in your database? If you do not use Java, please remove the Java tag?

Comment: @sln the required output is modified slightly. Could you pleas help on this?

Comment: `But I need to remove backslash which is present at the end of each column` =  `"\\\\$",""`